# Tensors and Partial Differential Equations

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, tensors

Given the volume-fraction-averaged stress tensor (and assuming $2D$ space):
$$ \sigma_s = -p_s\mathbf{I}+\mu_s(\nabla \mathbf{v}_s + \nabla\mathbf{v}_w^T)+\lambda_s(\nabla\cdot \mathbf{v}_s)\mathbf{I} $$
I want to find $ \frac{\partial \sigma_s}{\partial x} $. My confusion however is how to take partial derivatives of a tensor and specifically the meaning of the tensor in the middle term. In this example, $\mathbf{v}_s = (v_{s1},v_{s2})$ and $\mathbf{v}_w = (v_{w1},v_{w2})$. So I believe:
$$ \nabla \mathbf{v}_s = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial y} \\ \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix} $$
Finding a similar expression for $\nabla\mathbf{v}_w^T$, it would then follow that:
$$ \nabla \mathbf{v}_s + \nabla\mathbf{v}_w^T = \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v_{w1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_{w2}}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial x}+\frac{\partial v_{w1}}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial y}+\frac{\partial v_{w2}}{\partial y}  \end{bmatrix} $$
Is this correct?

Additionally, for the last term, am I correct that this is equal to:
$$\lambda_s(\nabla\cdot\mathbf{v}_s)\mathbf{I} = \lambda_s\begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial y}\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} = \lambda_s \begin{bmatrix} \frac{\partial v_{s1}}{\partial x} \\ \frac{\partial v_{s2}}{\partial y} \end{bmatrix}  $$
It seems to me that one of these must be incorrect since they have different dimensions but it's not clear to me which.

For perspective, this paper I am following along gives a momentum balance equation of the form:
$$ 0 = \nabla\cdot(\alpha\sigma_s)+\mathbf{F}_{sw} $$
I was hoping to write this out componentwise in order to estimate the orders of the terms that appear. To do this, it appears that it is necessary to find the partial derivatives of $\sigma_s$ though. Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Comment: $\nabla \cdot (F,G) = \partial_1 F + \partial _2 G$ is the divergence. It is a scalar valued function, not a 1x2 matrix. The $\lambda\nabla\cdot v I$ is a multiple of the identity.

Comment: Ah, yes of course! So is my expression for the middle term correct?

Comment: It's either that or its transpose, depending on convention.